# What does those symbols on these wires mean? (USB)

Tags: usb, microphone

[image]I got this cable while fixing my Microphone (Audio Technica ATR2500-USB). It came from a USB B type connector at the bottom of the mic. Does anyone know what does these symbols on the wire correspond to? (+5v, -5v, D+, D-, etc.)

UPDATE: I'm so sorry for making this post misleading. There was supposedly a photo to be included in this post. And, I know that is GND, not -5v. Thanks :>

Comment: Try searching for "USB pinout" using your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2):

"+5V" is the (or is connected to the) positive supply from the USB host, which should be 5V. "-5V" is mislabeled and should actually be the supply return, commonly called "ground". "D+" and "D-" are the D+ and D- USB data channels.